# Filings having multiple Filers on SEC Website, explanation?

Tags: sec, earnings

I found several filings having dozens of filers, here's a taste: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1265235/000095013706009934/0000950137-06-009934-index.htm

I understand that some may have 2 filers: one filing agent and the actual subject but how is the example above possible, can somebody help me make sense of this? It's a quarterly report, how would one find out which entity the actual subject is? I am trying to find this out programatically.

Thanks a lot

Comment: They all link to the same report.  They are all entities of the holding corp.  Every 10-Q filing of the entities held by the holding corp links back to the holding company's 10-Q.  The 10-Q is for Bally Total Fitness Holding Corp.

Comment: In this example I know you are right but Is there a clear indicator for that?